# Store and retrieve imageUri into shared preferences doesn't work

Tags: image, sharedpreferences, uri

I can set the image of an imageview with an given imageUri:

```
iv_test.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

I convert the imageUri to string and store the string to shared preferences:

```
 editor.putString("SPR_imageURI",imageUri.toString());  
 editor.apply();
```

Inside "onCreate" i retrieve the string from shared preferences and parse it to Uri again.

```
 String string = mySPR.getString("SPR_imageURI","");
 Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(string);
```

Then i set the image of the imageview with the retrieved imageUri but it shows nothing.

```
iv_test.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

However, just to check if the conversion works, i tried the following successfully:

```
String string = imageUri.toString();
Uri test_uri = Uri.parse(string);
iv_test.setImageURI(test_uri);
```

Note: 
I can store and retrieve any other string into shared preferences without any problems. As long as i don't close the app, storing of the uri works fine too.

So i would appreciate any ideas why the storage of imageUri won't work this way.

Comment: I finally found the solution: I have to add a permission to the manifest.     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>